# Computing cumulative distribution function of Random Variable X in terms of Random Variable Y

Tags: probability

Let X be a random variable with cumulative distribution function FX. Let
Y = X + 5. Compute FY , the cumulative distribution function of Y , in terms of FX.

This is my attempt...

Fy(Y) = P(Y<=y)

since Y = X + 5

Fy(Y) = P(X+5<=y)

= P(X<=y)-5

= Fx(Y-5)

Fy= Y-5

Not too sure if this is right or if I performed the right steps.

Comment: $F_Y(y)=F_X(y-5)$ is correct. Everything is right here, except possibly for the last bit "Fy=Y-5" where it is unclear what you mean.

Comment: So do i just end it at Fy(Y) = Fx(y-5)? All this stuff is new to me and very confusing.